# How can I access one Git repo from two machines?

Tags: git, ssh

I have a repo for work, normally accessed from my work machine. On that machine, I have created an SSH key-pair using `ssh-keygen` in Git Bash. The key-pair on both machines is `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`.

If I log in as my work user, and try to add my home key to the work user account, I get told somebody else has already registered that key. If I generate a second home key, i.e. `id_rsa2` and `id_rsa.pub2`, I get an authentication failure.

From this, I surmise that Git, by default, only looks for and uses the original `id_rsa.pub` file when authenticating with the repo host, which incidentally, is BitBucket. I'm guessing I somehow have to tell Git which key to use for which repo, or something, but right now I am lost and asking how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple private ssh keys using a `~/.ssh/config` file.

```
Host fromhome
  HostName yourServer
  User git
  IdentityFile "~/.ssh/id_rsa2"

Host fromwork
  HostName yourServer 
  User git
  IdentityFile "~/.ssh/id_rsa"
```

That file can reference both private keys and let you use 2 different ssh urls.

From Home:

```
cd /path/to/local/repo
git remote set-url origin fromhome:<user>/yourrepo
```

From work:

```
cd /path/to/local/repo
git remote set-url origin fromwork:<user>/yourrepo
```

That being said, from home or work, you only need one set of public/private key, so you don't need the config file.
If you regenerate a private `id_rsa` private key at home, you will be able to register its new public key on BitBucket side.
At home, the `.ssh/config` is only useful if you had already a private/public ssh key used for something else.

[Rahul Gupta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6557203/rahul-gupta) asks:

> Why can't I just copy the `.ssh` directory to the second machine and use the same?

This is considered as bad practice: a private key is supposed to remain... *private*, as in "not copied around".
Plus you can easily revoke a private key (by removing its authorized key from the `.authorized_keys` ssh server). If the private key was used on many machines, you would revoke access for way more than you intended by removing *one* public key on the server side.